# Custom Angular provider not working but no error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I started a basic angular project using the yeoman angular generator.

I added very few things to the app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 
'ngAnimate', 
'ngCookies', 
'ngResource', 
'ngSanitize', 
'loginService',
'restangular']).
config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  return $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  }).state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  });
}).run(function($state) {
  return $state.transitionTo('home');
});
```

`loginService` is a custom *Provider*, and apparently it doesn't have any js error. I am loading it from index.html and apparently the browser console doesn't give me any error.
For sake of clarity I've taken the [login-service](https://github.com/mrgamer/angular-login-example/blob/master/src/login-service.js) from [angular-login-example](https://github.com/mrgamer/angular-login-example)

The problem is that whenever I add this service to the app thigs stop to work and I don't get any error message. I did try to comment the dependency `loginService` when I declare my app module but doesn't seems to help.

The **only thing** that makes the app work is to completely remove `<script src="scripts/services/login-service.js"></script>` tag from the index.html

Maybe I do have a js error within it? But the browser's console seems happy tough.

**EDIT:** I generate my script from coffescript, maybe this could have something to do with it, I mean something happening during this conversion that I've missed? Here the [login-services in coffeeScript](https://gist.github.com/LeonardoGentile/66f41ffbfe1246ab406e) and after the conversion in [javascript](https://gist.github.com/LeonardoGentile/b4fda841f1ee07a68425)

Comment: My guess is the problem is in your `login-service.js`, can you post that? Your `myApp` module looks fine to me.

Comment: I've updated the question with 2 gist, the original coffescript version and the javascript file after the compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file starts with

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

By doing this, you **redefine** the module 'myApp', saying it has no dependency at all. What you want is to get a reference to the module 'myApp', not redefining it. You thus need

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

Comment: thanks, would you be kind to point me to that part of the documentation? For each example I've seen everyone is defining their modules in a different way

Comment: Beat me to it :-) thats what I suspected